# Making dictionary item frequency

Tags: python

I want to know why it's not counting the element ?
I made an key then in each iteration it should increase the value.

```
def isAnagram( s, t):
    if len(s) != len(t):
        return False 
    d_1 = {}
    d_2 = {}
    for i in range(len(s)):
        d_1[s[i]] =+ 1
        d_2[t[i]] =+ 1
    print(d_1)
    print(d_2)
    return True if d_1 == d_2 else False  

s = 'aabb'
t = 'bbaa'
print(isAnagram(s,t))
```

```
OUTPUT : 
d_1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 1}
d_2 = {'b': 1, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting ?

Comment: d_1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 1}
d_2 = {'b': 1, 'a': 1}

Comment: You're writing `=+` instead of `+=` ; just fixing that will not be enough, since `a += 1` will raise an error if `a` doesn't exist. You'll have to test whether the key already exists.

Comment: It Worked, Thanks a lot. 
But what's the difference in meaning to an interpreter?

Comment: `= +1` means you put positive one into a map and `+= 1` you add one to the value inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have an error, to add value to the variable you need to do

```
d_1[s[i]] += 1
d_2[t[i]] += 1
```

Second, the function fails because you need to define the key and value before modifying the value.
Working function:

```
def isAnagram( s, t):
    if len(s) != len(t):
        return False 
    d_1 = {}
    d_2 = {}
    for i in range(len(s)):
        try: # checking if the character in the dictionary exists
            d_1[s[i]]
        except KeyError:
            d_1[s[i]] = 0
        try: # checking if the character in the dictionary exists
            d_2[t[i]] 
        except KeyError:
            d_2[t[i]] = 0
        d_1[s[i]] += 1
        d_2[t[i]] += 1
    print(d_1)
    print(d_2)
    return True if d_1 == d_2 else False  

s = 'aabb'
t = 'bbaa'
print(isAnagram(s,t))
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in comments. you should use `+=` instead of `=+`.
`+=` means adding the value to the previous value stored. while
`=+` here means `=` (assigning the value)

```py
def isAnagram(s, t):
    if len(s) != len(t):
        return False
    d_1 = {}
    d_2 = {}
    for i in range(len(s)):
        d_1[s[i]] += 1
        d_2[t[i]] += 1
    print(d_1)
    print(d_2)
    return True if d_1 == d_2 else False  

s = 'aabb'
t = 'bbaa'
print(isAnagram(s,t))
```

Answer (score -1):

add a .lower() to Domagoj's answer to be case-insensitive.
so this will also work:

s = 'Betrug'.lower()
t = 'Erbgut'.lower()

{'b': 1, 'e': 1, 't': 1, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 'g': 1}
{'e': 1, 'r': 1, 'b': 1, 'g': 1, 'u': 1, 't': 1}
True